# Angular application crashes with JitCompiler error

Tags: angular, angular8

I've taken over a project and was tasked to add more features. So I added some modules and components and while the application starts and runs it crashes.

```
Uncaught Error: Component EnquiryComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (compiler.js:27198)
    at compiler.js:27174
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:27171
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:27160)
    at compiler.js:27088
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2400)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:27087)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:27047)
```

The EnquiryComponent is imported in the app-module.ts

```
import { EnquiryComponent as CustomerEnquiryComponent } from './customer/enquiry/enquiry.component';
```

The CustomerEnquiryComponent is imported along with several other components. I can run `ng compile` just fine and it finishes in 20s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it inside your declarations section of the module:

```
@NgModule({
declarations:[CustomerEnquiryComponent] 
})
```